# How can I make a desktop build in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I know that the short answer is "you can't". Desktop builds are no longer a part of TFS 2010.

However, I figure that I can somehow, if I install a build agent on my machine, and direct the WF to ***not*** get the latest version or a shelveset, and use the existing workspace, I should be able to fake it.

The problem is that between the theory and practice is a large gap in my knowledge. Can anyone think of a way this could work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution:

A client that wants to build locally (i.e. desktop-builds) needs to install a **Build Controller** *and* **Build Agent** on his desktop machine. Then he needs to pick that controller for the build.

In the build template, the **Get** activity needs to be deleted, and the **Create Workspace** activity needs to be replaced with a **Get Workspace**, to use an existing one.

Finally, remove the command to copy to a drop folder. You're building locally. Not necessary.

Assaf

Answer (score 0):

What is it, exactly, that you're trying to accomplish? Why not just setup a build agent on your machine and configure an incremental build to run on it? You could pass shelvesets into it via the Queue Build dialog or use a separate branch to keep your sources separate from the rest of your teams.

Comment: see the private builds section on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181722.aspx#queue_private

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish, is to allow users to run the build workflow on their current **checked out** version, in their own workspace, on their own machine. 
I want to accomplish the following:
1. Avoid checking-in unsafe changes
2. Avoid having to shelve & unshelve changes, as some of these might be exclusively checked-out (e.g. .csproj) and thus **can't** be unshelved.
3. Make use of their own resources to perform the build.